# VS2015 C# WPF: How to add event handler?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I use the below code to add an event handler in C#. It always works in VS2017 or VS2019.

```
async void deviceChangedHandler(object s, EventArgs e) => await DevicesChangedEventAsync();
_deviceWatcher.DeviceChanged += deviceChangedHandler;
```

Today when I used it in VS2015. I got error: The name 'async' does not exist in the current context. Not sure what has gone wrong.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local functions weren't introduced until C# 7.0, which is supported by VS 2017.

Of course, what you're trying to do can be simplified to:

```
_deviceWatcher.DeviceChanged += (_, args) => DevicesChangedEventAsync();
```

which, in addition to being shorter, would work as far back as C# 4.0 (VS 2010).  The newer language features aren't actually necessary or even helpful here.

Comment: the event won't trigger.

Comment: @Ken Then you need to figure out why the event isn't being triggered, as the code shown has nothing to do with it, as it isn't triggering the event, merely adding a handler.